# Hibernate criteria equal on property

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a `Language:`

```
class Language {
    private Site site;
    private Locale locale;
    //other usual stuff
}
```

I have a `Site`:

```
class Site {
    private Long id;
    private Set<Language> languages;
    private Locale primeLocale;
    //usual stuff
}
```

And I've been struggling for days to get primary language by site's id, is it even possible to filter by properties in hibernate?
What i want is equivalent to this sql:

```
select *
from languages as l
join sites as s on l.locale = s.primeLocale
where l.siteId = (some id)
```

I tried following:

```
public Language getPrimeLanguageBySite(Long siteId) {
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Language.class).add(Restrictions.eq("site.id", siteId))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("site.primeLocale", Property.forName("locale")));
        return (Language)criteria.setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();
    }
```

But it fails with `unknown column 'site.primeLocale' in 'where clause'`, and I can't even form my question without describing all this, so my attempts with google failed, could somebody please help?
**How can I get language by siteId and site's primeLocale?**

Answer (score 2):

You should use an alias and eqProperty.

```
public Language getPrimeLanguageBySite(Long siteId) {    
  Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Language.class, "language");   
  c.createAlias("language.site", "site");
  c.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("site.primeLocale", "language.locale"));
  c.add(Restrictions.eq("site.id", siteId));
  return c.setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use an [alias](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations).

```
public Language getPrimeLanguageBySite(Long siteId) {    
  Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Language.class, "language");   
  c.createAlias("language.site", "site");
  c.add(Restrictions.eq("site.primeLocale", "language.locale"));
  c.add(Restrictions.eq("site.id", siteId));
  return c.setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the same error `Unknown column 'site1_.primeLocale' in 'where clause'`, I am definitely sure this column exists, checked via mysql, but hibernate thinks otherwise(

Comment: Are you sure the column is mapped in your Hibernate config?

Comment: Definitely, extraction from Site.hbm.xml: `<property name="primeLocale" column="primeLocale" type="java.util.Locale"/>` @Benjamin_Diaz

Comment: eq does not work with other properties you shall be using eqProperty